# Drawing text in a specific spot using flutter

Tags: flutter

For text drawing on canvas, a fairly simple construction can be used:

```
void drawName(Canvas context, String name, double x, double y)
{
    TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800], fontSize: 24.0,
            fontFamily: 'Roboto'), text: name);
    TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
        text: span, textAlign: TextAlign.left, textDirection: `
`           TextDirection.ltr);
    tp.layout();
    tp.paint(context, new Offset(x, y));
}
```

Is it possible to draw text at an angle, for example 45 degrees, or 90 degrees (vertically from the bottom up)?

Comment: It is unclear if you are looking for "How to rotate text" or "How to position text somewhere". I provided an answer for Rotation

Comment: I just wrote an answer - hopefully it clarifies rotating on a canvas which seems like what you're asking about. But if you're actually looking to write text with each character upright but the direction of the overall text be down, you'll probably have to just insert a bunch of newlines!

Answer (score 3):

To rotate text on a canvas, you can use canvas transforms rather than rotating the entire canvas.

That looks something like this:

```
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  // save is optional, only needed you want to draw other things non-rotated & translated
  canvas.save();
  canvas.translate(100.0, 100.0);
  canvas.rotate(3.14159/4.0);

  TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800], fontSize: 24.0,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto'), text: "text");
  TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
      text: span, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
  tp.layout();
  tp.paint(canvas, new Offset(0.0, 0.0));
  // optional, if you saved earlier
  canvas.restore();
}
```

Note that I'm translating then rotating, because if you translate after or even use the offset you'll probably get a different result than what you want. Also, once you start using transforms (translate & rotate) you probably want to save the transform state and then restore after you draw whatever you want transformed, at least if you're drawing anything other than the rotated text.

Answer (score 1):

A function that draws text at a specified angle:

```
 void drawText(Canvas context, String name, double x, double y, double angleRotationInRadians)
 {
      context.save();
          context.translate(x, y);
          context.rotate(angleRotationInRadians);
          TextSpan span = new TextSpan(
              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800], fontSize: 24.0,
              fontFamily: 'Roboto'), text: name);
          TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(
              text: span, textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
          tp.layout();
          tp.paint(context, new Offset(0.0,0.0));
      context.restore();
  }
```

PS."rmtmckenzie", thank a lot for your help.

Comment: Offset.zero is a nice constant to use there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a Transformation. There is a general [Transform Widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html), but there is also a more specific [RotatedBox Widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html) that sounds like it will be a perfect fit for you.

```
new RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 3,
  child: const Text('Hello World!'),
)
```

If you need more control over the rotation (to use something other than 90 degree increments) you should be able to achieve this the [Transform Widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html) and a [Matrix4.rotationZ](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/vector_math_64/Matrix4/Matrix4.rotationZ.html)

```
    new Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: new Transform(
        transform: new Matrix4.rotationZ(-0.785398),
        child: new Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          color: const Color(0xFFE8581C),
          child: const Text('Apartment for rent!'),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: The OP was asking for rotating text on canvas, I think.